# Clarify on enriched categories

Tags: category-theory

The teacher mentioned that, given a category $\mathbb C$ enriched in a (monoidal) category $\mathbb V$,the category $\mathbb C^{op}$ is enriched in $\mathbb V$ iff $\mathbb V$ is commutative. However I don't see where actually is requested the commutativity of the product of $\mathbb V$; for example, in the case of a usual category (i.e. enriched in sets) $\mathbb C$, when I verify that the definition of $\mathbb C^{op}$ gives raise to a category, I don't see where I use that the product of sets is commutative. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The composition in the opposite category is
$$C^\mathrm{op}(x,y)\otimes C^\mathrm{op}(y,z)=C(y,x)\otimes C(z,y)\cong C(z,y)\otimes C(y,z)\xrightarrow{\circ}C(z,x)=C^\mathrm{op}(x,z)$$
and to define it you need the symmetry isomorphism in the middle.